# I want to combine these two php codes

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, hyperlink, popup

my php codes :

```
if(!empty($mp3Link)) { 

 $linkHtml = '<a href="'.$mp3Link.'">

   <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-542" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/dan.jpg" alt="link dow" width="249" height="64">
        </a>';

};
```

nowI want to add this code to it

```
header("Refresh:2; url=page2.php");
```

that's mean : When clicked img class, move to page2.php after 2 second

Answer (score 0):

you can put the header() call in a separate PHP file. I don't think this would be generally speaking a good idea, it will be better to create a javascript function that create a 2 seconds timer that will follow the link when the timer ends

Comment: I do not know  ...I want both $linkHtml and page2.php to work

Answer (score 0):

you can do using javascript/jquery

```
<img onClick="redirectLink(this)" my-link="http://www.google.com"  />

<script>
function redirectLink(attribute) {
var link = $(attribute).attr('my-link');
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href= link; // the redirect goes here
},2000); // 2 seconds
}
</script>
```

Comment: => use in php like this. 

if(!empty($mp3Link)) { 
 $linkHtml = '<img  onClick="redirectLink(this)"  my-link="'.$mp3Link.'"  class="alignnone size-full wp-image-542" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/dan.jpg" alt="link dow" width="249" height="64">';

};

Comment: and for js part , you need to add script  in footer or somewhere after "jquery.js".

Comment: I want this call to be made after calling $mp3Link after 2 seconds, my-link = "http://www.google.com" />